# Can't retrieve info as JSON if field has special characters using PHP/AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am using ajax to get some info from my database.  I use a page that will return the JSON row of information:

```
$get = DB::getInstance()->get($table, array($field, '=', $field_equals))->first();

echo json_encode($get);
```

Information is echo'd like this:

```
 {"id":"118","contact_id":"7","appt_status_id":"1","reason_id":"1","start":"1994-03-31 00:00:00","end":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","allDay":"0","pre_notes":"","post_notes":null}
```

I am now having an issue.  I am trying to pull the record/row information from a table called 'users'.  That table has a password field and a special field that is called 'salt'.  I learned to use the salt for better password hashing.  It is created at registration and is used to verify the username/password.

Either way here's a sample salt that can be found in a field:
     ’¯z„„{VÀZTÑÂÚÒJQeˆ.Ûù1¨˜3• ï_

I find that because of the special characters (I think?) no information will be echo'd from my ajax page! The ajax page just returns no results, when I know I should be getting a record's row information.  If I clear out the salts then the record information is echo'd as JSON.  So the salt field is the culprit.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: I'll have to read your suggestion.  I didn't mean to duplicate anything.  I'm not the same person as whoever asked the other question.  Let me see if I can figure this out then..... Thanks.

Comment: try using htmlentities($salt);

Comment: What would salt and password have to do with returning json? Surely you're not sending that to the client.

Comment: It is a very bad practice to store passwords directly in database or another storage. Store a result of hashing function like md5(md5(password) . salt) or something like this. You shouldn't compare password values on login. Compare a results of your function and a value recorded on registration for respective user

Comment: Also, salt is a kind of secret hardcoded constant, which is a part of password hashing function. It shouldn't be spoiled too.

Comment: thanks for the help.  I am not storing my passwords directly in my database.  I wasn't thinking though.  I shouldn't be returning all of this information client side.  that was silly of me. I actually use an Ajax query now that only returns the username.